# Jekyll plugin for lightboxing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

Yet another time that I don't like what already exists, so first, *this is what I want to build*:

I got one [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) directory structure, let it reside at `/opt/jekyll/`. Let HTML be served to `/var/www/blog/` via `jekyll build --config /opt/jekyll/_config.yml`.

I want a plugin which **"Problem 1"** goes through the files at `/opt/jekyll/images/` on each build (let one be named `/opt/jekyll/images/gng/gng01.jpg`) and serves them in `/var/www/blog/images/full/`, so gng01.jpg should be served as `/var/www/blog/images/full/gng/gng01.jpg`.

Simultaneously, it should **"Problem 2"** serve a thumbnail of it in `/var/www/blog/thumbs/` (essentially calling `convert /var/www/blog/images/full/gng/gng01.jpg -resize 150x150^ -gravity center -extent 150x150 /var/www/blog/images/thumbs/gng/gng01.jpg`, might do so through [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)). Thumbnail size should be configurable in **"Problem 3"** `_config.yml`.

Also, it should **"Problem 4"** register one Liquid-Tag and **"Problem 5"** one Liquid-Environment, so that I can use it like this:

```
{% gallery "myGallery" %}
  {% image "gng/gng01.jpg" "This is the picture gng01.jpg associated with gng" %}
{% endgallery %}
```

*I am just asking for helpful resources and hints* as I haven't worked with ruby before (because I avoided and used something I am familiar with whenever I had the choice). I am not asking for finished code. So:

I found [this "slideshow"-plugin](https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-slideshow)([code](https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-slideshow/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll_slideshow.rb)). If I read correctly, that does at least part of my **"Problem 1"**, **"Problem 2"** and **"Problem 3"** - registering a tag, converting images and reading config values. Yet I can't get that plugin to work on my server, so I don't know if I can modify it to handle the pictures exactly the way I want.

It might even be impossible or at least incredibly hacky with jekyll to copy `/opt/jekyll/images/` to `/var/www/blog/images/full/` without copying it to `/var/www/blog/images/`. In that case I consider thumbnailing from `/opt/jekyll/images/full/` to `/opt/jekyll/images/thumbs/` and serve the whole thing.

In the [slideshow-code](https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-slideshow/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll_slideshow.rb) there is:

```
site.static_files.each do |file|
  if (File.extname(file.path).downcase == ('.jpg' || '.png')) &&
        (!File.basename(file.path).include? "-thumb")
```

This seems to apply to every PNG or JPG inside the base directory. Can I restrict that to the images/ directory for efficiency? Is `static_files` fully populated by default?

Also, can I define a Generator and a Tag in the same rb-file?

I only find "tag" plugins on the web, which show how to add a Tag for my **"Problem 4"**, but none have "environments" to solve my **"Problem 5"** (Not even sure if that's what they're called, but this is the name in TeX).

Comment: Five problems = five questions on SO. This question will certainly be closed with reason "unclear what you're asking". Take the time,  explain your problems and you will get answers. But one question at a time.

Comment: Not removed yet? Anyway, I figured out everything I needed on my own (mostly thanks to the brainstorming I did to write this question). Plugin works now.